# HTML5 <Video> "Loop" with a gap or delay of few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, timedelay

I am using the HTML 5 "Video" tag to show the video on my page with the "Loop" feature or attribute.

Is there any way we can add a **delay or gap** between video using the "**Loop**" attribute??

```
<video id="myVideo" autoplay loop src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4">
```

Please refer the link to see the Video tag code > "**http://jsfiddle.net/nrf5fbh8/1/**"

Please suggest!

---

**Updated my code, my video tag DO NOT have controls.**

Thanks!

Comment: One way to do it would be to use a [listener](http://www.steveworkman.com/html5-2/javascript/2012/interacting-with-html5-video-players/) combined with a [JS timeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) to tell it to replay the video after **x** amount of seconds once the video finishes playing(instead of using the loop attribute).

Comment: Can you please explain using the link I provided by showing what you mean?? would be a great help!!! Thanks

Comment: Hey APAD1: Just to update, my video tag donot have controls showing.. just updated my question too!

Comment: No problem, removing controls will not affect my solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above, basically instead of using the loop attribute you can set up a listener and place a function within the listener to replay the video after a specified amount of time(in milliseconds) once the video has ended. The JS would look like this:

```
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
function myHandler(e) {
    console.log('ended');
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('myVideo').play();
    }, 5000);
}
```

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrf5fbh8/4/)

Comment: Thanks APAD1! I like your solution.. it works well in fiddle, but not sure whats the issue I'm getting error when I add the same code in my page...

Comment: "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: Any idea what must be the issue?

Comment: Move the script to the bottom of the page, right before the closing `</body>` tag. That error means that it is looking for an element that doesn't exist yet because the Javascript is being fired before the element is placed in the DOM.

Comment: Oops.. that's silly me.. Thanks Buddy your solutions rocks!!! It works well now!!

Comment: No problem at all, happy it helped!

Comment: Make sure the attribute `loop` is not present in your html `video` tag :)