# Stopping the video for 3 seconds and then continue

Tags: javascript, html

I have video background on my web page, I want to stop this video for 3-4 sec and then continue (loop). How can I do this?

I have this code:

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
     <source src="video/Great_Coffee.mp4" type="video/mp4"> Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 <Video> "Loop" with a gap or delay of few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058967/html5-video-loop-with-a-gap-or-delay-of-few-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how you could do it with JavaScript:

```js
const video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
video.currentTime = 5; // Video will jump to 5th second
video.pause();
setInterval(() => {
 video.play();
}, 3000);
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" autoplay loop>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: and what about if i want to be video stoped at another picture a  mean in the middle on video

Comment: @Danny I have updated my answer. You could use `video.currentTime = 5;` to start the video after 5 seconds. You may see the picture of the 5th second when the video is paused.