# Increase the video loop iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I was working on a landing video section which has a video playing in the background and according to the video there is some text that will change with respect to the video depending on the video timing. The text animation is using keyframes. I've got it working but I am stuck at a point I.e., delay while looping.

On window load(starting of video) everything works fine but when the video comes to an end and starts back to the loop there is like 1 second or fraction of seconds of delay for the video to restart after the loop. "This is my actual problem" when the video restarts the text changes which is in keyframes delays and has its iteration count set to infinite. The text is not matching with the video the second time. when I stay on that section like for a minute video is not matching with the text slides.

Is there any way to delay the animation with CSS or jQuery that the text delays when video starts looping for the second time.

Here is the [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/Wahed98666/pen/OwbBmq)

Below is the code I am working on.

```css
body {
  background-color: #02001b;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 1455px;
  height: 799px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header-section section {
  width: 45%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.as-main-heading {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.as-main-excerpt {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.header-section .first,
.header-section .second,
.header-section .third,
.header-section .fourth {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.header-section .first {
  animation-name: anim-1;
}

.header-section .second {
  animation-name: anim-2;
}

.header-section .third {
  animation-name: anim-3;
}

.header-section .fourth {
  animation-name: anim-4;
}

@keyframes anim-1 {
  0%,
  8% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 54%;
  }
  8%,
  16% {
    bottom: 25%;
    top: 54%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25%,
  100% {
    bottom: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
  0%,
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  32%,
  40% {
    bottom: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    bottom: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-3 {
  0%,
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  58%,
  66% {
    bottom: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75%,
  100% {
    bottom: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-4 {
  0%,
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  81%,
  92% {
    bottom: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo" height="800px;">
      <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div class="landing-header">
    <div class="header-section">
      <section>
        <h2 class="as-main-heading">Story of a bunny</h2>
        <div class="as-main-excerpt first">
          <p>Here comes a butterfly</p>
        </div>
        <div class="as-main-excerpt second">
          <p>Bunny See's the butterfly</p>
        </div>
        <div class="as-main-excerpt third">
          <p>Butterfly Sitting on the flower</p>
        </div>
        <div class="as-main-excerpt fourth">
          <p>An apple falls on the butterfly</p>
        </div>
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried [delaying the loop instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32058967/html5-video-loop-with-a-gap-or-delay-of-few-seconds)?

Comment: @Adelin I don't want to delay the loop of the video I want to delay the Keyframes loop for the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it quite simply by restarting your whole animation every time the video starts a new loop.

To detect this event, you can listen for the Media event [`onplaying`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/playing).
To restart your animation, you can set a class (e.g `.playing`) on a parent element which will tell when the animation should be active, and then remove this class and [force a *reflow*](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) so that the browser deactivates the animation, and finally set back the playing class.

```js
var header = document.querySelector('.header-section');
myVideo.onplaying = function(e) {
  header.classList.remove('playing'); // deactivate the animation
  header.offsetWidth; // force a reflow
  header.classList.add('playing'); // reactivate the animation
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #02001b;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 1455px;
  height: 799px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header-section section {
  width: 45%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.as-main-heading {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.as-main-excerpt {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.header-section .first,
.header-section .second,
.header-section .third,
.header-section .fourth {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
/* The animation is set only when the parent has the .playing class */
.header-section.playing .first {
  animation-name: anim-1;
}

.header-section.playing .second {
  animation-name: anim-2;
}

.header-section.playing .third {
  animation-name: anim-3;
}

.header-section.playing .fourth {
  animation-name: anim-4;
}

@keyframes anim-1 {
  0%,
  8% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 54%;
  }
  8%,
  16% {
    bottom: 25%;
    top: 54%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25%,
  100% {
    bottom: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-2 {
  0%,
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  32%,
  40% {
    bottom: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50%,
  100% {
    bottom: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-3 {
  0%,
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  58%,
  66% {
    bottom: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75%,
  100% {
    bottom: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-4 {
  0%,
  75% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  81%,
  92% {
    bottom: 25%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo" height="800px;">
      <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div class="landing-header">
    <div class="header-section">
      <section>
        <h2 class="as-main-heading">Story of a bunny</h2>
        <div class="as-main-excerpt first">
          <p>Here comes a butterfly</p>
        </div>
        <div class="as-main-excerpt second">
          <p>Bunny See's the butterfly</p>
        </div>
        <div class="as-main-excerpt third">
          <p>Butterfly Sitting on the flower</p>
        </div>
        <div class="as-main-excerpt fourth">
          <p>An apple falls on the butterfly</p>
        </div>
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Regarding the comment that changes everything (i.e you need to have a pause and play feature), then the best is probably to get rid of the CSS animations altogether, and to control your elements all from js (helped by CSS transitions):

```js
var header = document.querySelector('.header-section');
var chapters = [0, 0.96, 1.92, 2.9, 4.2, 5.4, 6.5, 7.2, 9, 11];
var classes = ['', 'first-in', 'first-out', 'second-in', 'second-out', 'third-in', 'third-out', 'fourth-in', 'fourth-out', ''];

var currentFrame = 0;
myVideo.ontimeupdate = function() {
  var nextFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % chapters.length;
  if(myVideo.currentTime >= chapters[nextFrame] || myVideo.currentTime < chapters[currentFrame]) {
//    if(classes[currentFrame]) header.classList.remove(classes[currentFrame]);
    if(classes[nextFrame]) header.classList.add(classes[nextFrame]);
    currentFrame = nextFrame;
    if(!nextFrame) // did loop
      classes.forEach(remove);
    header.offsetTop;
  }

};
function remove(classname) {
  if(classname)header.classList.remove(classname);
}

onclick = function(e) {
  if(myVideo.paused) myVideo.play();
  else myVideo.pause();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #02001b;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 1455px;
  height: 799px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header-section section {
  width: 45%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.as-main-heading {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.as-main-excerpt {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.header-section .as-main-excerpt {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 54%;
    transition-property: opacity bottom top;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    
}

.header-section.first-in .first,
  .header-section.second-in .second,
  .header-section.third-in .third,
  .header-section.fourth-in .fourth {
    bottom: 25%;
    top: 54%;
    opacity: 1;
}
.header-section.first-out .first,
  .header-section.second-out .second,
  .header-section.third-out .third,
  .header-section.fourth-out .fourth {
    bottom: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    opacity: 0;
}
video {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo" height="800px;">
      <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div class="landing-header">
    <div class="header-section playing">
      <section>
        <h2 class="as-main-heading">Story of a bunny</h2>
        <div class="as-main-excerpt first">
          <p>Here comes a butterfly</p>
        </div>
        <div class="as-main-excerpt second">
          <p>Bunny See's the butterfly</p>
        </div>
        <div class="as-main-excerpt third">
          <p>Butterfly Sitting on the flower</p>
        </div>
        <div class="as-main-excerpt fourth">
          <p>An apple falls on the butterfly</p>
        </div>
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question, I got a play and pause functionality on the video, that is if I click anywhere on the video the video should pause and play. I got my video loop working with your help but I want those text changing keyframes to stop on click too. Would that be possible? Here is an updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/Wahed98666/pen/wxoRQE)

Comment: You saved my day that is working, exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

You can delay your text animation using [animation-delay](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay)

```
.header-section .first,
.header-section .second,
.header-section .third,
.header-section .fourth {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

Comment: I want the animation delay for the text from the second time and so on.. of the video loop Because It's working as expected at the first time.

Comment: @Mohammedwahedkhan Define a CSS class which applies the CSS `delay-animation`, then add this class to your `.header-section .first,...` when the video ends for the first time

Comment: Could you spare some time and make those changes in the codepen and link it here.